# DES decryption in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cryptography

I need to decrypt DES code in my windows Phone 8 project. I tried to use DESCryptoServiceProvide but I think it is not available for windows phone 8(although MSDN says it is). I also tried BouncyCastle library but they also failed. So please suggest/help with any other 3rd party DES decrypt library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try free [CryptoBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cryptobb.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product - it includes implementations for many encryption algorithms including DES and there are assemblies available for WP8.